# Atom editor consumes 100% CPU

Tags: cpu, atom-editor

Only starting Atom editor nearly freezes my PC, because its using 100 % CPU. I didn't open any project I only started the editor.

Anyone experiences the same issue? Can someone help me out? This way it is not usable.

Comment: Does the same issue occur after re-installing it. Does the same issue occur with other similar tools?

Comment: reinstalled several times. Also old releases. There are plenty of users having the same issue on several forums. But no concrete solution found so far. My other tools all working fine. I have a clean new Virtual Machine VMWare I use and VMWare is running fine.

Comment: Try Timecop via "Packages" -> "Timecop". This should break down the startup time of Atom and give some insight about it. Maybe that helps already.

Comment: The problem is not loading time. The problem is, once the editor is started its running under 100% CPU. The hole PC freezes for hours.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed the same issue on my Ubuntu 16.
I had added my whole home directory as a project folder on the left.
After removing it the CPU usage of atom went nearly to 0%.

Comment: You saved my day :D